# iproute2 mark vs manual rule in table

Tags: iptables, iproute2

I have a problem!
So, I have two providers and a routing server on CentOS7.
I can not get the marking to work through the second provider. The essence is this:
With the first provider everything is fine, it is not highlighted in a separate table.
A simple rule for MASQUERADE and a rule for a firewall.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s MY_IP -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m mac --mac-source MY_MAC -j ACCEPT
```

The second provider sits in a separate table, in the table itself there is only the default route and a couple of rules:

```
ip route show table 2
default via GATEWAY_OF_PROVIDER dev eth2.2

ip rule show
from GATEWAY_OF_PROVIDER lookup 2
from all fwmark 0x2 lookup 2
```

Outcome:
If I add a rule:

```
ip rule add from MY_IP lookup 2
```

, then everything works, and if I add

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s MY_IP -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

, everything breaks at the provider's gateway.

trace with manual rule:

```
  1    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  gate.dtbyh.ru [192.168.0.XX]
  2    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  ipXXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.ipblk.stnsk.ru [195.189.218.73]
  3     1 ms     1 ms    <1 мс  gw.stnsk.ru [XX.XX.XX.XX]
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  startel-gw.mega-com.ru [XXX.XX.XX.XX]
  5     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  kuchum-xe-0-0-2.yndx.net [XX.XX.XX.XX]
  6    46 ms    61 ms    50 ms  sverdlov-xe-0-0-3.yndx.net [213.180.213.68]
  7    46 ms    46 ms    46 ms  styri-et-10-3-0-901.yndx.net [213.180.213.18]
  8    63 ms    47 ms    47 ms  m9-p2-eth-trunk8.yndx.net [87.250.239.127]
```

trace with mark rule:

```
  1    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  gate [192.168.0.XX]
  2     *       <1 мс    <1 мс  ipXXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.ipblk.stnsk.ru [XX.XXX.XXX.XX]
  3     *        *        *     
  4     *        *        *
```

ie the marking is work, but it does not let go of the gateway.

```
sysctl:
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
RHEL>6 sysctl:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
```